# I am trying to access pixel values to calculate WH kernel(summed area table) using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

```
integral(img,isum,CV_32F); //calculating integral of the image.




for(int i=0;i<e2;i++)//e2 is columns
{
        for(int j=0;j<=e1;j++)//e1 is rows
        {
            /*intensity = isum.at<Vec3f>(j,i);
            m1v = intensity.val[0];

            intensity = isum.at<Vec3f>((j+(p/2)),i);
            m2v=  intensity.val[0];*/

            /*intensity = isum.at<Vec3f>((j+p),i);
            m3v= intensity.val[0];*/

            /*intensity = isum.at<Vec3f>(j,(i+p));
            m4v= intensity.val[0];*/


            intensity = isum.at<Vec3f>((j+(p/2)),i+p);
            m5v= intensity.val[0];

            /*intensity = isum.at<Vec3f>(j+p,i+p);
            m6v= intensity.val[0];

            //2*(m2v)+m6v+m4v-2*(m5v)-m1v-m3v;
            featurev=2*(m5v)+m1v+m3v-2*(m2v)-m4v-m6v;
            featurev/=(p*p);

            cout<<k<<". featureV: "<<featurev<<endl;
            k++;*/
        }
}// p is patch size.
```

when I run this code it is causing an exception. I have tried interchanging the coordinates.
I am finding the integral of an input image and accessing the pixels of isum. 
Please help me with the code.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

classic buffer overflow...

```
for(int i=0;i<e2;i++)//e2 is columns
{
   //...
   intensity = isum.at<Vec3f>((j+(p/2)),i+p); // <- this will overflow
```

if you add an amount p to i, you'll either need to save a border of size p at the right end,

```
for(int i=0;i<e2-p;i++)//e2 is columns
```

or do manual bounds checking :

```
if ( i+p < cols ) ...
```

same applies to j/rows

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The first solution worked for me. Just one more thing, it is taking almost a minute to run, is there any way to reduce the time?? Anyways thanks.

Comment: yea, i can imagine. but optimizing this ain't easy. look into parallel_for, openmp, gpu stuff.

Comment: btw, is your integral() function that different from the builtin one ?

Comment: I am using the built-in function of opencv. Is there any other alternative??

Comment: ah sorry ignore, i got confused.

Comment: My problem is this a sub function which has to be called in Java for Android development which has time and memory constraints

Comment: but, - if you could formulate it as a kernel Mat - you could use [filter2D()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#filter2d), which is quite optimised already

Comment: it would replace your double-for-loop. unfortunately i am not familiar enough with wH kernels to formulate it properly